# MVC ASP.net Multiple Views trying to store tags

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tags

Model:

```
public class PublishedSongViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string SongName { get; set; }

    //...
    [Required]
    public IEnumerable<string> Category { get; set; }

}

public class CategoryViewModel
{
    public short Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SongCategoryViewModel> SongCategory { get; set; }
}

public class SongCategoryViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int PublishedSongId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public short CategoryId { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model IList<PublishedSongViewModel>
@using (Html.BeginForm("PublishMusic", "Publish", FormMethod.Post, new { @enctype = "multipart/form-data", @id = "form-upload" }))
            {
             @Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model[i].Category, new SelectList(//Categories list here), new { @class  = "form-control dl_Categories             ", Multiple = "Multiple" })
            }
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult PublishMusic(IEnumerable<PublishedSongViewModel> songDetails)
        {
            if (songDetails != null)
            {
                IEnumerable<PublishedSongViewModel> savedSongs = (IEnumerable<PublishedSongViewModel>)(Session["UserSongs"]);
                var lookupDetails = songDetails.ToDictionary(song => song.Id, song => song);

                if (savedSongs != null)
                {
                    foreach (var publishedSong in savedSongs)
                    {
                        var key = publishedSong.Id;
                        if (lookupDetails.ContainsKey(key))
                        {
                            var details = lookupDetails[key];
                            publishedSong.SongName = details.SongName;
                        }

                        db.SongCategories.Add(new SongCategoryViewModel { PublishedSongId = key, CategoryId = //categories id that user typed in on editorFor});
                        db.PublishedSongs.Add(publishedSong);
                        db.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }
            }

            return View("Index");
        }
```

I'v filled CategoryViewModel table up with data in my SQL.

1) How do I get the titles of CategoryViewModel and pass them in the SelectList(//Here) parameter in my viewmodel?

2) In the PublishMusic Action, how do I get the CategoryId for the SongCategoryViewModel from the one or more categories that the user selected from songDetails.Category?

I am not sure if I am on the right track with this. basically the categories are like tags, the user can select more than one. I'v also cut out unessential code to make easier to read.

Comment: Add a property to your view model - `IEnumerable<CategoryViewModel> CategoryList` and populate it with your categories. Then in the view - `@Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model[i].Category, new SelectList(Model.CategoryList, "Id ", "Title"), new { ... })`. However this does not quite make sense since `Category` is `IEnumerable<string>` suggesting you need `ListBoxFor()` so its unclear what your trying to do.

Comment: Are you really editing multiple instances of `PublishedSongViewModel` and select one category for each, or do you want to edit one `PublishedSongViewModel` and select multiple categories for it?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I am allowing users to select the categories that they can associate the song with, so it will be multiple categories to one publishedSong model. Like I said, I am not sure if what I have wrote is correct. I have used others code to help me. So I will try what you have suggested so far tommorow.

Comment: In that case your model in the view and the post method needs to be `@model PublishedSongViewModel` and then `@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.Category, Model.CategoryList)` and in the post method, `Category` will be an array of the selected ID's